# Performing mathematical calculations inside asp.net repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I'm trying to multiply two numbers together from a DataBinder.eval on the front end asp page but its just returning 0.

In the database the values are as follows;

PPI = 0.45
MDPI = 0.5

But it just returns 0 for both.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFire">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LocationName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PPI")) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PPI") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MDPI")) %>
            </td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can I do it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFire">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("LocationName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("SqrMtr") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#String.Format("{0}", Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("PPI"))) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("PPI") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# String.Format("{0}",Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MDPI"))) %>
            </td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to convert the things in to `Integer`

instead of that you should try to convert it into `decimal` first and than need to multiply:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFire">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LocationName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PPI")) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PPI") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SqrMtr")) * Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MDPI")) %>
            </td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>
            <td>WORK OUT</td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%= %>
```

instead of

```
<%# %>
```

The latter is a databinding expression, which you are doing yourself by using the DataBinder.Eval method.

See [msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) for an explanation on the differences.